# What is that construction? What does it mean?

Tags: java, modelmapper

I use ModelMapper and I found construction like this:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
```

I understand that there is generic type `<List<String>>`but what about this `{}.getType()`?
Is it some kind of lambda? Why there is no =>?

Comment: `new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}` is an instance of an anonymous subclass.

Comment: It's a new anonymous subclass that is constructed on the fly.